# .net chart with columns and different scales (plus a few more questions)

Tags: asp.net, mschart

Below is a graph as I have it so far.  It has 1 area, with 5 data series

The graph is over the course of a month, as you can see all of the tuesday's are grouped, wednesdays, etc.

[image]

1. I would like to be able to label each individual bar with the actual date.  Ideally, this would be directly below the bar, and then below that label would be the existing tuesday/wednesday/etc label.
2. There is another metric of 'processed items' (Items from here on out) that I would like to indicate.  My thought is a label that's *above* the bar.  To the side a little with a line indicating which bar it's referring to.
3. If there was a way to do 2 instead with a different scale on the right side (meaning y labels are on the right side), that would be perfect.  Here is an example of what I mean:  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Please note that this is *not* using the ASP.Net control.  This is in an http handler where I'm using the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting namespace and directly instantiating everything and then converting it to png.